# Join two gifs in ffmpeg one after another

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to join two gifs one after another.

I'm trying to use this command

```
ffmpeg -i wordcut.gif -i firstwordcut.gif -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1[v]' -map '[v]' finished.gif
```

but I'm getting this error

```
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x5610077949a0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 320x569, SAR 64:64) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x3413, SAR 63:64)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x5610077949a0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Answer depends on how you want to deal with different sized GIFs. Do you want to enforce a specific size they should all fit into? Or just simply use the same size as the first input? Or something else?

Comment: @llogan Which ever is the smaller of the two since upscaling is bad